# Why isn’t every subgroup of a Finite Group Cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I’m trying to prove or disprove wether every subgroup of a finite group is cyclic or not. I came up with this proof:

$G$ is a finite group of order $k$, with elements $g_1,…,g_k$, then every $g_i\in G$ will generate a cyclic subgroup $H_i\subseteq G$ such that $H_i=\langle g_i \rangle$, hence, $G$ has at most $k$ subgroups. The precise count of how many subgroups is not necessary.
Finally, since every subgroup $H_i=\langle g_i\rangle$ is generated by a single element, every subgroup of $G$ is Cyclic.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: So $G$ itself is cyclic ...

Comment: Why do you think that every subgroup is generated by only one element?

Comment: Why though? Isn’t the fact that $G$  is finite enough to ensure $\langle g \rangle$ will cycle back for every $g \in G$?

Comment: How about $\langle g_1, g_2 \rangle$?

Comment: Actually $\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic also when $G$ is infinite, by the way

Comment: @Alex, because maybe i didn’t wrote it explicitly, but i am assuming that $\langle g \rangle=x\in G| x=g^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez You need $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (because you want inverses)

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was a mistake in my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have shown that every *cyclic* subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ of $G$ is cyclic. This is not very surprising. It doesn't imply that *all* subgroups of $G$ are cyclic, though. The easiest counterexample is $G=S_n$ with the subgroup $H=A_n$ for $n\ge 4$, which is not cyclic, because it is not even abelian.

Comment: Your example is certainly correct but I would say that the easiest counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @AndreaMori Yes, I admit this is also easy. But the example $S_n$ and $A_n$ doesn't need three factors and also gives a nonabelian example.

Comment: Convincing as usual.

Answer (score 4):

Take a non-cyclic group $G$ and any group $H$. Then, $K:=G\times\{1_H\}\cong G$ and $K\le G\times H$.